# Is this a contradicting definition for the symmetrical difference $\Delta$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The book I'm studying with has the following definition of the symmetrical difference:

$$ M_1\Delta M_2 = \{ x | ( x\in M_1 \lor x\in M_2 ) \land \lnot(x\in M_1 \land x\in M_2)\} $$

However, when I try to expand the the negated conjunction in the latter half of this definition, I arrive at the following contradictory defintion:

$$ M_1\Delta M_2 = \{ x | ( x\in M_1 \lor x\in M_2 ) \land (x\notin M_1 \lor x\notin M_2)\} $$

So, is that definition simply wrong or am I not even supposed to expand parts of definitions for some reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You distributed the symbol $\lnot$ correctly. In fact, you can go further and write 
$$ 
\begin{align*}
M_1\Delta M_2 &= \{ x : (( x\in M_1 \lor x\in M_2 ) \land x\notin M_1) 
\lor ( ( x\in M_1 \lor x\in M_2 ) \land x\notin M_2)\} \\ 
&= \{ x : x\in (M_2\setminus M_1)  
\lor x\in (M_1 \setminus M_2) \}. 
\end{align*} 
$$
I added the parentheses in the second equality to make the sets more clear. Furthermore, you can draw a [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) to have a visual understanding of the symmetric difference.

Comment: Thank you, I think I now know where the fault lies in my reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x \in M_1 \vee x \in M_2$ and $x \notin M_1 \vee x \notin M_2$ are *not actually contradictory*. In particular, if $x \in M_1$ and $x \notin M_2$, then $x \in M_1 \vee x \in M_2$ is true and $x \notin M_1 \vee x \notin M_2$ is also true (and similarly for $x \notin M_1$ and $x \in M_2$).

In general, $x \in M_1 \vee x \in M_2$ is true whenever $x$ is in $M_1$ or $M_2$ and $x \notin M_1 \vee x \notin M_2$ is true whenever $x$ is not contained in one of $M_1$ or $M_2$.

So, pretty much, everything is ok!

Comment: Thanks, now I'm a bit less confused!

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction in

Person P  (2) is either a man or a woman and (2) person P either is not a man OR is not a woman.

That is : person P (1) belongs to the union of the sets M and W, but (2) does not belong to the intersection of these two sets.

Or, if you prefer : (1) there is *at least one* set to which person P *belongs*, AND (2) there is *at least one* set to which person P does *not* belong.

The fact that the  formula  : (M OR W) & ( ~M OR ~W) is not a contradiction is shown by the fact that it's truth value is not " false" in all possible cases. It is false only when M and W are both false ( which makes " M OR W" false) , or both true ( which makes the secund conjunct false).

[image]

These 2 cases of falsehood correspond exactly to the 2 cases where an object does ***not*** belong to the symmetric diffference of two sets : $x\notin A\Delta B$ if and only if :

(1) $x\notin A$ AND $\notin B$

OR

(2) $x\in A$ & $\in B$.

Answer (score 0):

The definition simply says: $x$ is in $M_1$ or $M_2$ but **not** in both at the same time. So it's $(M_1 \cup M2) \setminus (M_1 \cap M_2)$ and can also be written as $(M_1 \setminus M_2) \cup (M_2 \setminus M_1)$, which consists of two disjoint areas in a Venn diagram, as can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), e.g.